# Overwrite and Store Numerical Incremented Value in Variable

Tags: objective-c

So I am just a few months into Objective-c and have been writing a fairly simple program that will prompt the user for a **`firstName`**, **`lastName`** and let's just say a **`favoriteColor`**.  I then have these user inputs stored via outputting the contents to a `.txt` file.  Each time the program is executed, a person object (*with a full name and favorite color*) is added to the list in a  `.txt` file via the **`NSOutputStream`** class.

What I want to do is have a sequential ticket system in place.  So each time the program is executed, a ticket number (*lets call this variable* **`topTicket`** *for clarity's sake*) is assigned to the new person object and printed out as an ID of sorts along with the name and color.

So let's say after the first 2 times I run my project that the text file contains the following:

```
FAVORITE COLOR INVENTORY

Name:  John Doe
Favorite Color:  Red
Ticket:  #031354

Name:  Jane Doe
Favorite Color:  Blue
Ticket:  #031355
```

Then i want the ticket variable (**`topTicket`**) to be the following next time I open my project files:

```
topTicket = 031356
```

I would like to know how I can have the program overwrite this initial value each time it is executed.  Therefor the next time I open up my project in xCode, after having run it once earlier in the day, the topTicket will now be one more than it was before (*031354 in this case*), having incremented itself and overwritten the previous value.  That way all I have to do is call this `topTicket` variable every time when writing to the `.txt` file instead of requiring user input.

I hope I am making sense.  I would love any suggestions or guidance as to how I should go about this.  ...maybe I am overthinking things haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish that is to use `NSUserDefaults`. You can store a value with `-setInteger:forKey:` and read a value with `-intergerForKey:`. Sample code:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSInteger ticketNumber = [defaults integerForKey:@"lastTicketNumber"];
ticketNumber++;
// use it
[defaults setInteger:ticketNumber forKey:@"lastTicketNumber"];
```

I think at one point in your project you want to save all data including user data. In that case you should save the ticket number at a place, where you store the other data, whatever it is. This is to keep data consistently.

Comment: Thank you, it took me an hour or so to really grasp the whole concept but it is working just great now!

Comment: @James Please mark the A as correct, so others find it easier.